# Переписать методы toString

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

Покажется глупым, но я не понимаю как это сделать в данном случае, чтобы из одного класса передать в другой информацию, а потом начать с ней уже работать)

Есть такой Json

```
{
"success": true,
"data": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "АР Крым"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Винницкая область"
    },
```

Парсится с помощью Jackson на 2 класса, Pojo и DataPojo

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)public class Pojo {
public Pojo(){}
private boolean success;
private List<Pojo> data;

@JsonProperty("data")
public List<Pojo> getDataPojo() {
    return data;
}

public void setDataPojo(List<Pojo> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

// getters & setters
@JsonProperty("success")
public boolean isSuccessPojo() {
    return success;
}

public void setSuccessPojo(boolean success) {
    this.success = success;
}
public String toString() {//???

}
```

DataPojo

```
public class DataPojo {
private String id, name;
// getters & setters

public String getIdDataPojo() {
    return id;
}

public void setIdDataPojo(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNameDataPojo() {
    return name;
}

public void setNameDataPojo(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String toString() {
    return this.name+this.id;//???
}
```

Ну и собствено хочу тут начать уже ее присваивать.

```
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,regions, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG,"login response"+ response);
            try {
                ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
                Pojo pojo=mapper.readValue(response,Pojo.class);
                System.out.println(pojo.toString());

            }catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Накосячили вы тут, автор :) Сравните определение поля `data` в моем ответе с вашим кодом. Должно быть `List<DataPojo> data` !!!

Comment: Уберите аннотации у методов, они там не к месту. И пользуйтесь автогенерацией геттеров и сеттеров в IDE, на ваших можно глаз сломать :)

Comment: Спасибо) Накосячил, правда.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно собственноручно написать метод `toString` в том виде, в каком вы хотите. Можно сгенерировать метод `toString` в среде разработки и подправить. 
**IDE** предложит список полей класса, которые необходимо включить в `toString` - поправьте результат, если он вас не устроит. Я скопировал ваш класс, сгенерировал автоматически и вот что у меня получилось:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Pojo{" +
            "success=" + success +
            ", data=" + data +
            '}';
}
```

Поскольку data это List, можно подправить вот так:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Pojo{" +
            "success=" + success +
            ", data=" + Arrays.toString(data.toArray()) +
            '}';
}
```

Если вывести на экран это `System.out.println(pojo.toString());`, то получится:

```
Pojo{success=true, data=[..., ..., ...]}
```

Можете манипулировать с этим, как хотите.
Ваш класс по умолчанию наследуется от класса Object, и используя аннотацию @Override вы переопределяете дефолтный метод класса, тем самым, когда вы будете вызывать toString у любого объекта этого класса, результат будет таким, какой вы сделаете.

Comment: К сожалению на массив выдает exception  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object[] java.util.List.toArray()' on a null object reference.
 а data=[null]

Comment: Это потому что у вас поле `data` равно `null`. А почему, смотрите мой коммент к вопросу.